# C++, Classes, Const, and strange syntax

Tags: c++, class, reference, constants

I was re-reading c++ primer(4th ed.) today - the section on member functions and const references etc, and I came up with this wierd little program:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class ConstCheater
{
public:
    ConstCheater(int avalue) : ccp(this), value(avalue) {}
    ConstCheater& getccp() const {return *ccp;}
    int value;
private:
    ConstCheater* ccp;
};

int main()
{
    const ConstCheater cc(7); //Initialize the value to 7
    cout << cc.value << endl;
    cc.getccp().value = 4;    //Now setting it to 4, even though it's const!
    cout << cc.value << endl;
    cc.value = 4;             //This is illegal
    return 0;
}
```

My question is - why does c++ allow syntax such as this? Why can I edit normal data members in a class when it's declared const? Isn't the POINT of const to make it so that you can't modify values?

Comment: You can work around most safety mechanisms of C++ because the language is based upon the idea that the programmer knows perfectly well what he is doing. Your program hardly looks like an "accident" to me. If you absolutely *want* to shoot yourself in the foot, go ahead and do so. C++ won't stop you.

Comment: @FredOverflow, in this case it's obvious because he's *trying* to make it obvious, but even if it's clear why this is happening it's still an interesting conceptual problem to address because one can imagine this happening by accident in a convoluted way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the answer by Tony that you marked as correct is incorrect, and the answer by Michael Burr is correct.

To put what he said more clearly (for me at least):

There are two potential places for misunderstanding:

1. The way implicit const works
2. The way that `this` is interpreted during construction of a const object

---

#### 1. Implicit Const

Implicit const (the constification internal to `ConstCheater` when it is made `const`) doesn't turn `cc` into a `pointer-to-const` but rather a `const-pointer`, that is to say when you do this:

```
  const ConstCheater cc(7);
```

Internally goes from:

```
  ConstCheater * ccp;
```

...to...

```
  ConstCheater * const ccp;
```

...rather than the...

```
  const ConstCheater * ccp;
```

that may have been expected.

#### 2. Construction of `const` object

The stranger thing is though is that `this` is allowed to be passed to `cpp`'s initializer in the constructor since `this`, one would think, should be treated as a `pointer-to-const`, and thus not a valid value to pass to a `const-pointer`.

That is to say one might expect:

```
 ...: ccp(this) ... // expected to fail but doesnt
```

to fail because conceptually you might expect that this was (somewhat) equivalent to:

```
 const ConstCheater         cc(7);
 const ConstCheater * const this = &cc; // const-pointer-to-const
```

and thus you would think that:

```
 ConstCheater * const ccp = this; //expected error!
```

would fail! But it doesn't because apparently during construction apparently `this` is treated specially as if it was:

```
 const ConstCheater * this = &cc;
```

and thus the object is effectively not const during construction.

I'm not sure I understand completely the reasoning, but Michael Burr points out there appears to be a logical and technical barrier to providing the expected behavior so the standard seems to carve out the current somewhat odd behavior.

I recently asked a related question which was: [Why does C++ not have a const constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936124/why-does-c-not-have-a-const-constructor) but thus far haven't really understood completely the reasoning why it would be untenable, though I suppose it would place a burden on C++ developers to have to define an awkward const constructor for any class they'd like to create const object of.

Comment: Bit of a late answer :) - But what you're saying makes perfect sense

Answer (score 6):

Even though `getccp()` is a `const` method it makes no promises what you do with the reference it returns. The method itself does not modify the object and therefore does not break the rules.

If it returned a `const ConstCheater&` then that would be different.

As your example shows, there is much more complexity to `const` than just applying it to an object. the C++ FAQ has a section on [const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) and in particular [it covers the case](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.11) you are highlighting here.

Comment: I don't think that FAQ covers this case… it glosses over the implementation of those functions, which on the face of it would seem to require a `const_cast` somewhere.

Comment: How does it not cover it? The example they give is a `const` method with the following declaration: `std::string& name_evil() const;` which is very similar to the example Schnommus gave: `ConstCheater& getccp() const` they are both const methods returning a non-const reference allowing external code to modify a (probably) private member of an object.

Comment: @Tony: the issue here is he managed to create a non-const reference to const data without the use of `const_cast`, which is not quite what you're talking about.

Comment: @Dennis: Only the object created here `const ConstCheater cc(7);` is const, the data inside it is not explicitly marked as const. Having a const object means we can only call const methods, which he does, but the pointer/reference returned (which in this case happens to point to the same object) is not marked as const. Pointers & references do not "inherit" constness from the object they point to, it's up to the interface and internals of the class to ensure the const contract is adhered to.

Comment: @Tony: all members of a const object are themselves const. So there is no well defined way to change `cc.value`.  Yes, the const-ness of `cc` does not change the const-ness of `*ccp`, but the inverse is also true. Try to assign `ccp` to `this` in any method except the constructor and you'll get a compile time error for just that reason.

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, you are correct about the trying to assign to `*ccp`. I've even managed to confuse myself about the way `const` works :)

Comment: I dont believe this answer is correctly addresses the issue in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor is allowed to modify the value of a `const` object, yes. But if it weren't, what could it do?

Since the constructor has such access, it can "forward" it to someone else or "save" it for later. Of course, doing so might be a bad idea.

This is one instance where the safety mechanisms of C++ do not prevent you from building an ill-formed program. C++ is anything but foolproof. So, just be careful!

Answer (score 2):

Objects do not become const until after their constructors finish doing their thing. So `this` is a pointer to non-const memory when you store it, but changes shortly after. That's why it allowed the assignment in the first place, because you did nothing wrong. That means `cpp` is a pointer to const, but the compiler doesn't realize that. It has no way to; you declared it non-const, after all. This is still undefined behavior, it's just not the type your compiler can ever really hope to help you catch.

Comment: +1, more specifically object lifetime doesn't begin until the constructor has finished, so the constructor is really looking at a blob of memory with few well-defined properties (§3.8/1, §3.8/3).

Answer (score 2):

The real issue isn't the behavior of `ConstCheater::getccp()` - it's  that there's no error on the line:

```
const ConstCheater cc(7);
```

which initializes a non-const pointer with what *should* be a const `this` pointer.  However, constructors cannot be `const` (9.3.2/5, but a bit of thought should make it obvious why).  So the constructor is allowed to initialize a non-const pointer with a pointer to a const object (or an object that's 'about to become' const). That's the hole you're driving though.

As to why it's allowed, I imagine it would be difficult for the standard to try to close the hole since it would have to enumerate all the ways that a constructor's `this` would have to be treated `const` and all the ways it would have to be treated `non-const` when constructing a const object.  That seems like a pretty difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

Your object is not entirely immutable: it's just the reference you created to point to it that's constant.

Comment: The object cannot legally be changed because it is directly declared `const`. Where is the `const` reference in this program?

Comment: In `main` he declares a const reference as `const ConstCheater cc(7);`

Comment: @Tony: That is not a reference, it is an object.

Answer (score 0):

What you are making `const` is the reference to a `ConstCheater`. Nothing in `ConstCheater` is making `value` a `const`.

Answer (score 0):

`const` qualifier restricts to call non-const methods on your object, so the problem is your design that allows you to give non-const reference to a member by a const method.
The common approach is

```
      Member& getccp()       {return *member;}
const Member& getccp() const {return *member;}
```

In some cases when logical constness of your object don't suffer from external modification of it's member you can allow

```
      Member& getccp() const {return *member;}
```

Another example of difference in logical and formal constness is the `mutable` members. I.e. mutable can be some term that was computed at the last `const` method's invoke, if you will get the same input at next invoke you can easily return stored value.