# Mutating constant object via pointer copied from 'this' in constructor

Tags: c++, this, constants

Example code:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() { instance = this; }
    int value = 0;
    static Foo * instance;
};

Foo * Foo::instance = nullptr;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Foo const foo;
    //foo.value = 1; // Compiler error, as expected.
    Foo::instance->value = 1; // Fine.
}
```

Here `foo` is constant, but can be modified via the static `instance` pointer, which is assigned the value of `this` in `Foo`'s constructor. Setting aside questions of why one might want to do something like this, my understanding is that there's nothing here that's technically incorrect.

I was confident this was safe, but in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656664/c-classes-const-and-strange-syntax) thread there seem to be some suggestions to the contrary. One person seems to describe a similar example as ill-formed, while someone else mentions undefined behavior.

Advisability aside, is this technically correct and safe? Or is there some issue I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely ill-advised to do so. For many reasons.

First, it's not thread-safe.

Second, mutating const-qualified objects by "unconsting" them by `const_cast`, or by the method that you've shown (or by any other method, for that matter), is simply *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: First, it's UB.  You are not allowed to modify a const object, no matter how you achieve it.

Comment: Added clarification, that no other method is allowed, either.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear, but the question wasn't about thread safety (which is a separate topic) or advisability, but rather about the technical correctness or lack thereof of mutating a constant object in the way shown. You did provide an answer to that question, which I appreciate. To provide a source for future readers, the answer appears to be documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv).

Comment: @scg in the Standard see [dcl.type.cv]/4 "Except that any class member declared mutable can be modified, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime results in undefined behavior."  (note that lifetime begins after the constructor completes, so the assignment in the constructor is allowed)